# How to split PDF files in PowerShell with iTextSharp (iText v.5)

Tags: powershell, itext

New to PowerShell; working through the Windows PowerShell Basics course on edX. But I like to have a project to help me learn.  Project: take a folder full of 2 page PDFs and split them each into 2 files, one for each page.

I found iTextSharp but I just cannot figure it out and it is driving me mad. I admit, I know nothing about .NET and next to nothing about PowerShell, so that is likely the main problem.  I'm hoping someone can help me out with the basics of iTextSharp in PowerShell.

Embarrassed to post the code I have so far, but here it is:

```
Add-Type -Path itextsharp.dll

$Files = Get-ChildItem -Filter *.PDF

if (-not (Test-Path .\page1)) {New-Item -Type Directory -Path .\page1}

foreach($File in $Files) { 
$EntireDoc = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.pdfreader -ArgumentList $File
$Page1 = $EntireDoc.GetPageContent(1)
$Page2 = $EntireDoc.GetPageContent(2)
}
```

Even if that did work, I'm not sure how to save the newly created PDF files.

Comment: `GetPageContent` is not what you need, it retrieves the instructions immediately in the page content stream. You should look for examples with `PdfCopy` that copy pages from one document to a new one. Or with `PdfStamper` first reducing the pages in a document and then writing this reduced pdf.

Comment: @mkl Thanks for the tip!  I will look into this.